# Where can I find a driver for my integrated video card?

Tags: drivers, integrated-graphics

Here is the DXDiagnostics:

[image]

Where can I find the driver for this particular video card? Googling yielded no results and I'm not familiar with integrated cards.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried Intel?

Comment: Yeah, can't find what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your OS from [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop+graphics+controllers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+HD+Graphics) and download the driver

Answer (score 1):

A good bet, would be to look up the motherboard manufacturer for the board with the embedded device.  Another place to look would be the manufacturer of the machine, if it was a homebuilt system.  Usually, from looking at the tech specs for the product, you can find the hardware name for your on board video, and then search for the drivers for that device.

As a general rule of thumb, even though a video card is on board, the OS doesn't know the difference between embedded and not.  It is just harder to distinguish the graphics card, because you cannot just unplug it and look for manufacturer stickers and such.

Comment: +1 This is often called the Chipset Driver package and you can identify the Intel chipset from System Information.